# How to check if a string from a list is inside another list?

Tags: python, list

Lets say i have 2 lists:

```
a=['LOL','GG','rofl']
b=['5 KEK muh bobo LOL', 'LOL KEK bobo bobo GG']
```

How do i check if first element in a can found in first element of b?

Answer (score 4):

Just that:

```
a[0] in b[0] # will return True or False
```

maybe you want to check all of them:

```
set(i for i in a for j in b if i in j)
```

or

```
{i for i in a for j in b if i in j} #Python 2.7+
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is actually very robust. You can just do.

```
a[0] in b[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know if it's in the string or not:

```
if a[0] in b[0]: pass
```

However, the above has the problem that both of these will return true:

```
if "LOL" in "a b LOL c": pass
if "LOL" in "a b xxLOLxx c": pass
```

So if you care about words vs. simple presence, as long as your delimiters are consistent:

```
if a[0] in b[0].split(" "): pass
```

If you need to know which word position:

```
idx = b[0].split().index(a[0]) # note, throws a ValueError if not in the list
```

If you need to know the position in the string:

```
idx = b[0].find(a[0]) # returns -1 if not found
```

If you want to know if each element from a is in the corresponding element of b (ignores extra entries on either list):

```
[(i[0] in i[1]) for i in zip(a, b)] # to check for simple membership
[(i[0] in i[1].split()) for i in zip(a, b)] # to check for whole words
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
a[0] in b[0]
```

which will return a True if the first element of a can be found in the first element of b, otherwise it will return False.